# Use svg pattern in css

Tags: css, svg

I have a codepne here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/vvOoJe

I have used css fill to add this pattern as a fill in another svg.

I also need to use the same pattern as a background in a div.

I have url-encoded the pattern svg and used it as the background-image of the div but the pattern does not display show.

How can I use the svg patteren as the background of the div.

```
.block{
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height: 66px;
  width: 200px;
          background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='4' width='4' %3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpattern id='diagonalHatching' width='3' height='3' patternTransform='rotate(45 0 0)' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cline x1='4' x2='4' y1='0' y2='10' style='stroke:red; stroke-width:5' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E");   

}
```

Comment: The background image SVG doesn't draw anything. It is just the pattern definition.  You have to actually apply it to a rectangle or something as @ccprog has pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw a rectangle in your background image and set its width/height, same as the `<svg>` element, to 100%. The content of the data uri would then look like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="diagonalHatching" width="3" height="3" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <line x1="4" x2="4" y1="0" y2="10" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:5"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatching)"/>
</svg>
```

Applied to the div:

```css
.block{
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height: 66px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='100%' width='100%'><defs><pattern id='diagonalHatching' width='3' height='3' patternTransform='rotate(45 0 0)' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'><line x1='4' x2='4' y1='0' y2='10' style='stroke:red; stroke-width:5'/></pattern></defs><rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(%23diagonalHatching)'/></svg>");   

}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```